# SpringMvc controller class is not working

Tags: java, spring-mvc

It's a simple function, I need a data from `ShownMovieController` class, but I got nothing in index page, here is my code. Any suggestions?

running Java 8, Spring 5.1.

```
@Controller
public class ShownMovieController {
    @Autowired
    private ShownMovieService sms;
    @Autowired
    private  ShownMovieService fms;

    @RequestMapping(value="/index")
    public ModelAndView MovieDisplay(HttpRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){
        ModelAndView maView = new ModelAndView();
        List<ShownMovie> sm = sms.findShownMovie();
        List<ShownMovie> fm = fms.findForthcomingMovie();

        maView.addObject("shownMovies", sm);
        maView.addObject("forthcomingMovies", fm);
        return maView;
    }
}
```

My web.xml

[image]

and Package Explore:

[image]

my index page

```
<div class="row">
  <c:forEach item="${shownMovies }" var="shownMovie">
      <div class="imgFrame">
          <img src="${shownMovie.imgPath }">
          <button class="btn btn-danger imgBtn">Buy</button>
      </div>
  </c:forEach>
</div>
```

and springmvc-config.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.zyb.core.web.controller"></context:component-scan>

<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/includes/**" location="/includes/" />

<bean id="jspViewResource" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>
```

Comment: use @RestController annotation to top of the class.

Comment: sorry guy~I didn't put the complete code in here，i had already use the @Controller annotation

Comment: did you try to debug, does it enter to the controller? What is the endpoint for your request?

Comment: I think you need to add @RequestMapping(value="/") to your controller class. And your function only has a @RequestMapping(value="index") declaration (without the leading slash). This way the controller knows that it's in charge.

Comment: Why is your component scan set to the controller package, and not the top most package? Also, please do not paste images of code and config files, it makes it difficult to see everything all together.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your code before returning `maView` object

```
maView.setViewName("your jsp page name");
```

or add this in `ModelAndView` Constructor

```
ModelAndView maView = new ModelAndView("your jsp page name");
```

Everything should work fine after this.